Understanding the factorization of conditional independence from Kevin Murphy book 2
I am self-studying Kevin Murphy's book 2, and I want to clarify a simple derivation. On pages 156-157, a probabilistic graphical model is factorized. The pgm is shown as follows

In the probabilistic model shown below:
$$
p(\theta, D) = p(\theta_x)p(\theta_y) \prod_{n=1}^{N} p(y_n \mid \theta_y)p(x_n \mid y_n, \theta_x) \tag{4.38}
$$
It follows that:
$$
p(\theta, D) = \left[ p(\theta_y) \prod_{n=1}^{N} p(y_n \mid \theta_y) \right] \left[ p(\theta_x) \prod_{n=1}^{N} p(x_n \mid y_n, \theta_x) \right] \tag{4.39}
$$
The next step is written as:
$$
p(\theta, D) = \left[ p(\theta_y) p(D_y \mid \theta_y) \right] \left[ p(\theta_x) p(D_x \mid \theta_x) \right] \tag{4.40}
$$
where:
$$
D_y = \{y_n\}_{n=1}^{N} \quad \text{and} \quad D_x = \{x_n, y_n\}_{n=1}^{N}.
$$
My question is: can equation $(4.40)$ follow from $(4.39)$? Specifically, equation $(4.40)$ suggests a joint probability term $p(x_n, y_n \mid \theta_x)$ instead of the conditional term $p(x_n \mid y_n, \theta_x)$ in $(4.39)$.
I understand that the following is true:
$$
p(x_n \mid y_n, \theta_x) = \frac{p(x_n, y_n \mid \theta_x)}{p(y_n \mid \theta_x)}.
$$
But, how can equation $(4.40)$ follow unless we assume $y_n$ and $\theta_x$ are independent? Does observing $x_n$ make $y_n$ and $\theta_x$ independent? Can you explain the validity of the transition from $(4.39)$ to $(4.40)$?
